# Verfication of Proof: "$A$ is nowhere dense iff $\mathbb{R}\setminus \overline{A}$ is dense"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I hope life is going well. Is possible that I get some feedback on my proof for this problem; style, accuracy, succinctness, etc..? Thank you for reading this.

#### Problem

Show that a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense if and only if $\mathbb{R} \setminus A$ is dense.

#### Definitions Employed

*Nowhere dense*: A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense if $\overline(A)^{\mathrm{0}} = \emptyset$.

(Note): $x \in A^{\mathrm{o}} \iff \exists \epsilon > 0 : \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(x)\subseteq A$

*Dense*: A set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if, given any two real numbers $a, b$ it is possible to find a point $x \in A$ satisfying $a < x < b$.

#### My Attempt

($\Longrightarrow$) Suppose that a set $A \in \mathbb{R}$ is nowhere dense. Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \overline{A}$ we have $x \notin (\overline{A})^{\mathrm{o}}$, which means that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ we have $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(x) \nsubseteq \overline{A}$. Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any choice of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, there does not exist a point $ x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$ satisfying $a < x < b$, i.e. $(a,b) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$. Since $(a,b) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$, we know it must be the case that $(a,b) \subseteq \overline{A}$. This is a contradiction since we assumed that $A$ is nowhere dense, so $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$ must be dense.

($\Longleftarrow$) Conversely, if $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$ is dense, then for any choice of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $a < x < b$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$. This implies that for any choice of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ the non-empty open interval $(a,b) \nsubseteq (\overline{A})^{\mathrm{o}}$. Thus, $(\overline{A})^{\mathrm{o}} = \emptyset$, meaning that the set $A$ is nowhere dense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part is fine, but you don’t need to argue by contradiction in the first part. Suppose that $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is nowhere dense. (Note that there is no hyphen in *nowhere*.) We want to show that $\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ is dense, so let $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$. Then $(a,b)\nsubseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, since $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A=\varnothing$, so there is an $x\in(a,b)\setminus\operatorname{cl}A=(a,b)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)$. The points $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary (with $a<b$), so $\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ is dense.

**Added:** On taking a closer look, I see that I ought to comment on a couple of specific points. You wrote:

> Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any choice of $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, there does not exist a point $ x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$ satisfying $a < x < b$, i.e. $(a,b) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$.

This isn’t quite right. If $\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ is not dense in $\Bbb R$, there is at least one pair of real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$ and $(a,b)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)=\varnothing$. There may be other open intervals that do intersect $\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ or even are contained in it, so it’s not true for just any $a$ and $b$. Note too that the non-existence of a point $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ such that $a<x<b$ really does say more than just that $(a,b)\nsubseteq\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$: it says that $(a,b)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)=\varnothing$, which is what you actually need later.

> Since $(a,b) \nsubseteq \mathbb{R} \setminus \overline{A}$, we know it must be the case that $(a,b) \subseteq \overline{A}$.

This also isn’t quite right: $(a,b)\nsubseteq\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$ does not imply that $(a,b)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$. However, we actually know that there are $a$ and $b$ such that $(a,b)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)=\varnothing$, which **does** imply that $(a,b)\subseteq\operatorname{cl}A$, and you get the desired conclusion.

Comment: This explanation helps clarify the relationship between the concepts. Thank you. Now, would my argument by contradiction be considered simply unnecessary and maybe even excessive or it is inaccurate? I believe it's the former but would like to make sure. Also, I have upvoted your answer but will wait to give it the green check so people are more likely to offer their insights (to me it seems fewer people approach if there is the check, and I am looking for diverse advice, so I hope this makes sense). Edit - I have tried to upvote but do not have enough score on MathSE to do that yet.

Comment: @TrevorPaulMartin: You’re welcome. The argument by contradiction is unnecessary, but it’s not wrong in principle. On looking more closely just now I did see that you’d made a couple of errors in carrying it out, but once those are fixed, it’s a perfectly good argument. But the direct argument uses essentially the same tools, so there’s no advantage to arguing by contradiction, and some people do prefer to avoid unnecessary use of contradiction, if only on æsthetic grounds.

Comment: These comments are great and have furthered my understanding! I have added the green check mark. Thank you again!

Comment: @rodeo_flagellum: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Another "more topological" idea for $(\Rightarrow)$:

Let $A\subset \Bbb R$ nowhere dense. We want to proove that $\overline {\Bbb R\setminus \overline A}=\Bbb R$, which means that $\Bbb R\setminus \overline A$ is dense in $\Bbb R$. The first inclusion is trivial. It remains to show that $\Bbb R\subset \overline {\Bbb R\setminus \overline A}$ or that every real number is a limit point of $\Bbb R\setminus \overline A$. Let $x\in \Bbb R$ and $\epsilon>0$; if the sentence $\forall y\in [(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\setminus\{x\}]:=N^*_x(\epsilon) :y\in \overline A$ was true, then immediately $N^*_x(\epsilon)\subset \overline A$, which means that $\overline A$ contains an open set, so $(\overline A)^\circ \neq \varnothing$ -a contradiction, because $A$ is nowhere dense. Consequently the true proposition is $\exists y\in N^*_x(\epsilon) :y\notin \overline A$, so $\exists y:y\in N^*_x(\epsilon)\cap(\Bbb R\setminus \overline A)$, thus the arbitrary real $x$ is a limit point of $\Bbb R\setminus \overline A$.